# Elastic search and PySpark date_format_parsing error

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch, pyspark, logstash

I am currently working on a school project using spark streaming and elastic search.
I am collecting some reddit informations using a kafka connector. Spark is then connected to this topic and streams informations to elastic search.

The problem that I am facing is some weird elastic search error due to the date format.

```
date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers
```

My data contains a timestamp in the format

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

after some researches online, I understood that the problem was with the elastic search mapping (since it usese Jova-time). So I modified my mapping as follows

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "created_utc": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
            }
```

(this is just a part of my mapping)

Unfortunately, I've not solved the problem and, honestly, at the moment I don't really know what the problem could be.

Thank you very much !

At the origin, my date is a unix timestamp. 
Since I'd like to work with a normal timestamp, I've converted it as follows using spark's functions:

unix timestamp to timestamp string:

```
wordsDataFrame = wordsDataFrame.withColumn('created_utc', f.date_format(wordsDataFrame.created_utc.cast(dataType=tp.TimestampType()), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

string to timestamp type:

```
wordsDataFrame = wordsDataFrame.withColumn('created_utc', f.to_timestamp('created_utc', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

I've also tryed to modify the conversion using the same format required by elastic search:

```
wordsDataFrame = wordsDataFrame.withColumn('created_utc', f.to_timestamp('created_utc', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

but this gives me null dates.

Comment: Have you tried to put the found format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in the format clause of created_utc date field definition ?

Comment: @Lupanoide What do you mean by that? 
Do you mean to convert the date of my collected data to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"?

However, to make things more clear I've updated the post with how the date is processed, since it starts as a unix timestamp.

Comment: I mean to declare the format in the mapping: "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "created_utc": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ||yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }

Comment: are you sure that f is not null?